# How to display a dynamic number of outputs in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

What I do:
I have a shiny App that returns every column of my csv as a verbatim ouput. I attached my current code (UI.R and Server.R) and the csv-File below.

**My Question**: I need to write such an app for many different csv-files that all have a variing number of columns. How do I do this automatically without having to write

```
output$myColumn01 = renderPrint({
as.character(D$Names)
})
```

and

```
h1("Names"),
verbatimTextOutput("myColumn01"),
```

for every column manually?

-

Here is my csv ("myCSV.csv"):

```
Names;Pages;Scores;Numbers
George;T;3;5
Jim;I;4;23
Jack;T;6;12
Anna;R;4;3
```

Here is my server.R-File:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


D = read.csv(file = "myCSV.csv", sep = ";")



output$myColumn01 = renderPrint({
as.character(D$Names)
})


output$myColumn02 = renderPrint({
as.character(D$Pages)
})


output$myColumn03 = renderPrint({
as.character(D$Scores)
})


output$myColumn04 = renderPrint({
as.character(D$Numbers)
})



})
```

Here is my ui.R-File:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title =  "Sessions"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350,
    collapsed = TRUE,
     ""
  ),



  dashboardBody(


  h1("Names"),
  verbatimTextOutput("myColumn01"),
  h1("Pages"),
  verbatimTextOutput("myColumn02"),
  h1("Scores"),
  verbatimTextOutput("myColumn03"),
  h1("Numbers"),
  verbatimTextOutput("myColumn04")

  )
))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it what you expect ?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  D = read.csv(file = "myCSV.csv", sep = ";")

  lapply(1:ncol(D), function(i){
    output[[sprintf("myColumn%02d",i)]] <- 
      renderPrint({
        as.character(D[[colnames(D)[i]]])
      })
  })

  output$ui <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:ncol(D), function(i){
      tagList(
        h1(colnames(D)[i]),
        verbatimTextOutput(sprintf("myColumn%02d",i))
      )
    })
  })

})


ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Sessions"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 350,
    collapsed = TRUE,
    ""
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    uiOutput("ui")

  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]